# Why isn't my zbar library upload to Amazon Lambda? Docker, Zappa

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, zbar, zappa

I'm trying to deploy a Django application to Amazon Lambda via Zappa.
The application uses pyzbar, which has the zbar or libzabar0 requirement.
In my Dockerfile, I install the zbar library, and in the local docker file my code runs correctly.
However, when I do `zappa update dev`, it provides an error that it can't find the zbar dependency. `ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library`

I have looked around, and I'm following this guide: https://blog.zappa.io/posts/docker-zappa-and-python3.
Ive added the dependency in the Dockerfile (see below) and a said it is working correctly.
I have also tried deploying zappa in the directory above (`/var/`) but then zappa complains that the zip file is too large.

Dockerfile

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.6

LABEL maintainer='me'

WORKDIR /var/task

# Fancy prompt to remind you are in zappashell
RUN echo 'export PS1="\[\e[36m\]zappashell>\[\e[m\] "' >> /root/.bashrc

# Add your extra requirements here e.g. postgres-devel 
# RUN yum install -y yourpackages

RUN yum clean all && \
    yum -y install zbar zbar-devel

CMD ["zappa"]
```

Zappa settings

```
{
    "dev": {
        "django_settings": "library.settings",
        "profile_name": null,
        "project_name": "backend",
        "runtime": "python3.6",
        "s3_bucket": "bucket"
    }
}
```

Docker run command: 
`docker run -ti --env .env  -v "%cd%":/var/task -v ~/.aws/:/root/.aws -p "8000:8000" library bash`

My goal is to get it uploaded to Amazon Lambda and have the zbar library working correctly.
However, I get an ImportError: `ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library`.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Lambda won't have your local source tree, and won't run an interactive shell.  You might make the `docker run` command more closely resemble what you'll actually run in Lambda, which probably means `COPY`ing your local tree into the Docker image.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the python pip package from here: https://pypi.org/project/zbar/

Add zbar to your requirements.txt. Then it will be installed and uploaded in the python virtualenv:

active your virtualenv in the docker container:

```
source /var/task/venv/bin/activate
```

install the python libraries defined in the requirements.txt:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```